# 3 dimensional Mat returns a null Matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to initialise a 3 dimensional Mat in OpenCV as follows:

```
3d_matrix = Mat(3, sizes, CV_64FC1, double(0));
```

where `sizes` is an `int` of size `3`. `sizes` has the values `341`, `441` and `170`.

However, while debbugging I see that `3d_matrix` has `rows` and `cols` both set as `-1`.

When I try to write this matrix as an image it creates an empty image (ie it has no size), as expected.

Comment: Rows and cols are set to -1 for multidimensional matrices. So everything is normal here

Comment: Duh :P Thanks for your reply, I just had to project it onto a 2D Mat to display it.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Miki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5008845/miki) said, rows and cols are set to -1 for multidimensional matrices.

If you just have 3 dims, you can use something like:

```
cv::Mat threed_matrix = cv::Mat(341, 441, CV_64FC(170));
std::cout << "rows: " << threed_matrix.rows << std::endl
          << "cols: " << threed_matrix.cols << std::endl
          << "channels(): " << threed_matrix.channels() << std::endl;
```

which gives:

```
rows: 341
cols: 441
channels(): 170
```

Note that channel size should not exceed `CV_CN_MAX`, which is currently `512` defined in OpenCV